# Making multiple asynchronous HTTP 2.0 requests with okhttp3

Tags: java, okhttp, http2

I am trying to use okhttp (3.4.1) to implement a HTTP 2.0 based client. Part of my requirement is to implement multiple asynchronous HTTP requests to different URLs with a callback to handle the response at a later time. 
However, with my current implementation, I see that I cannot get all my asynchronous requests to use the same TCP connection unless I make a blocking HTTP request from my main thread at the beginning. 
I understand that the enque() method used for asynchronous calls engages the dispatcher which seems to spawn a new thread for each of the requests.
Here is my code snippet:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

My async Get Request method looks as follows:

```
public void AsyncGet(String url) throws Exception {

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /* Some code */
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });

}
```

My synchronous Get Request is as follows:

```
public Response SyncGet(String url) throws Exception {

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Making a call sequence like the following triggers 2 TCP connections to the server.

```
AsyncGet(Url);
AsyncGet(Url2);
```

However, a call sequence like the following makes use of the same TCP connection.

```
SyncGet(Url);
AsyncGet(Url);
AsyncGet(Url2);
```

I have not debugged this but, it looks like OkHttp forces us to make a blocking HTTP request on the main thread first to possibly obtain the TCP connection context and then share that with other threads? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625035/when-using-http2-in-okhttp-why-multi-requests-to-the-same-host-didnt-use-just

Answer (score 0):

You can call async to and set sector to each call later on based on the sector you can distinguish the response of call. Try this code; I hope it will help you!

Create a separate class for api call:

```
public class RestApi {

    protected RestApiResponse serverResponse;
    protected Context c;

    public RestApi(RestApiResponse serverResponse, Context c) {
        this.serverResponse = serverResponse;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void postDataWithoutAuth(String url,String sector) {


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("response", call.request().body().toString());
                serverResponse.onErrorLoaded(call.request().body().toString(), sector);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                serverResponse.onResponseLoaded(response, sector);
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Then create an interface for callback

```
public interface RestApiResponse {

    public void onResponseLoaded(Response response, String sector);

    public void onErrorLoaded(String response, String sector);
}
```

and access it from your Activity like this

```
RestApi apicall = new RestApi(this, getBaseContext());
apicall.postDataWithoutAuthUrlEncoded("ur url","your sector");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must add that I am not developing my prototype for android. This is meant to be a pure desktop application with okhttp. To me it looks like, okhttp's current dispatcher module currently seems to lack this feature (unless we create a hack like the one mentioned in my question).